# Prevent Safari on iOS from auto scroll to an input on focus change

Tags: css, ios, webkit, mobile-safari

I have in my web app a login modal with a form of two fields. When user moves between the fields, the page auto scroll and move the modal. I’ve checked all the similar questions and have been trying all suggested solution but no one suits. Because of top navbar in the background being scrolled too (although it’s position=sticky) I’m guessing it’s and accessibility feature which I’ve wondered how to disable. Tip will help!

[image: Demo]